# Mostar resultados MYSQL en Horizontal

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Tengo la  base de DATOS creada en este formato.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el codigo que utilice para la consulta es el siguiente: solo que a la tabla clase aumente La columna **Bimestre** para demilitar la consulta.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover"> 

         <tbody>
         <tr>
          <td>N°</td>
          <td class="warning"><H3>APELLIDOS Y NOMBRES</H3></td>

<?php 
$consulta="SELECT * FROM clase WHERE bimestre='1BIM'";

$resultado=$link->query($consulta);

foreach ($resultado as $dia) {
    echo "<td>".$dia['fecha']."</td>";

}// cierra el foreach

echo "</tr>";

$tabla1="alumno";
$tabla2="lista";
$tabla3="clase";
$consultax="SELECT $tabla1.id,$tabla1.ap,$tabla1.am,$tabla1.nom,$tabla2.alumno_id,$tabla2.clase_id,$tabla2.estado FROM $tabla1,$tabla2 WHERE $tabla1.id=$tabla2.alumno_id ";
$resultadox=$link->query($consultax);
while ($row=$resultadox->fetch_array()) {
    $ap=$row['ap'];
    $am=$row['am'];
    $nom=$row['nom'];
    $id=$row['id'];
    $estado=$row['estado'];

    echo "<tr>";
    echo"<td>".$id."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$ap." ".$am." ".$nom."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$estado."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}


?>                        
</tbody>
</table>
```

el resultado final tendria que ser asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
 de antemano agradeceria su ayuda.

Comment: es solo para esos dos dias o las fechas son dinamicas,si es para esos dos dias hay una tecnica que se conoce como pivote si es para mas deberia resolverlo de alguna forma dinamica y va a ser un poco mas complicado pero calcularia que se puede.

Comment: es dinamica, el trabajo final es para por lo menos 20 fechas, es un registro pedagogico que estoy creando y todos lo colegas tienen hechos en excel pero yo estoy metido e}de lleno aprendiendo PHP pero me atasque en esta  parte -.-!

Comment: perfecto Milton, bueno voy a probar una forma de resolverlo si no me sale vemos si seria mejor cambiar el diseño.

Answer (score 1):

la base de datos así como la muestras facilita poco las cosas.
Yo separaría la estructura en 3 tablas: (Los nombres de las tablas son supuestos)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego, con PHP se puede lograr de una salida como la que propones.
Espero haberte ayudado, avisa si necesitas ayuda para continuar.
Saludos.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, voy a reestructurar la tabla: como haria la consulta con estas 3 tablas ?

Comment: Podes realizar una consulta sobre la tabla clase, limitando el rango de fechas que quieras. Luego recorres con un foreach el resultado de esta query y por cada bucle haces una consulta a la tabla asistencia con la correspondiente clase_id del bucle en el que estas... pero para armar la salida con el formato que deseas, mejor sería si subes tu código PHP y lo modificamos ahí mismo...

Comment: ok lo voy a trabajar esta noche  y vemos el resultado  gracias

Comment: hola Mauro, te cuento que el foreach que realice no logro hacer funcionar de acuerdo a mis necesidades  podrias corregir mi codigo por favor, edite el texto de la repgunta